# Oracle concatenation issue

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT
  tbl1.PYU_EMAIL,
  COUNT(tbl1.PYU_EMAIL) as TOTAL,
  ( SELECT ROWCONCAT( 'SELECT pyu_id FROM p_survey_invite WHERE pyu_email=' || tbl1.pyu_email ) FROM dual )
FROM p_survey_invite tbl1
GROUP BY tbl1.pyu_id, tbl1.pyu_email
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

hi all,

I keep getting 
ORA-04054: database link DIGITALVIDEOSYSTEMS.NET does not exist error

I suspect that when I concat the tbl1.pyu_email within the rowconcat function, the tbl1.pyu_email has @ char on it, which reflect to DB-LINK on oracle.

How do I tell oracle not to think @ is db link?

Comment: ROWCONCAT is not standard SQL (nor PL/SQL). I suggest you look at the methods described [in this article](http://www.oracle-base.com/articles/misc/StringAggregationTechniques.php) that will work better.

Comment: @gumpi: Can you include the definition of p_survey_invite in your question?

Comment: Instead of this ROWCONCAT, maybe try LISTAGG (see http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14072_01/server.112/e10592/functions087.htm)

Answer (score 4):

You should put quotes around your e-mail address:

```
SELECT
  tbl1.PYU_EMAIL,
  COUNT(tbl1.PYU_EMAIL) as TOTAL,
  ( SELECT ROWCONCAT( 'SELECT pyu_id FROM p_survey_invite WHERE pyu_email=''' || tbl1.pyu_email ||'''') FROM dual )
FROM p_survey_invite tbl1
GROUP BY tbl1.pyu_id, tbl1.pyu_email
ORDER BY total DESC;
```

You are passing a string to the ROWCONCAT() function which executes that string dynamically.  Your code concatenates a varchar2 column to the DML string.  Unless you include escaped quotes in the string what you pass (and the function tries to execute) is something like this:

```
SELECT pyu_id FROM p_survey_invite WHERE pyu_email=gumpi@example.com
```

And that's why it fails.

Comment: While it will work there are many problems with this implementation: performance will be suboptimal AND you leave yourself open to SQL injection (both because you're not using bind variables).

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - The dynamic SQL executes a string which consists of hard-coded boilerplate text and values from a column.  Not sure where you see the scope for SQL injection.  If somebody has the access to sneak a malicious value into P_SURVEY_INVITE there are lots of easier exploits they can probably kick off.

Comment: @APC: SQL injection vulnerability also means that you may get errors from non-malevolent legitimate entries (which could include quotes as part of the text). I did not realize that P_SURVEY_INVITE was a boilerplate/hard-coded table. Still, my comment stands in a general context: you are better off with a solution that prevents SQL injection and is more performant (several string aggregation methods exist).

Comment: @VincentMalgrat - I don't diagree that SQL Injection is A Bad Thing.  I simply think your other point, about using more standard and better optimised, is more pertinent.